# Сравнение строк не происходит

Tags: java, android, строки, сравнение

Есть `EditText` и одна кнопка. Когда нажимают на кнопку, если текст в `EditText` равен `12345`, то уведомление должен быть `true`, если нет то `false`. Когда я напишу `12345` все равно уведомление `false`. Не знаю почему.

Вот мой код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: оформите код в виде текста, а не скриншота. Старайтесь давать вопросу заголовок, отражающий суть проблемы, а не маловразумительное "Помогите .."

Answer (score 13):

Не сравнивайте строки используя операторы == и !=. Они сравнивают строки по ссылке, а вам нужно по значению. Вместо этого используйте функцию equals.

```
if("12345".equals(i)) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
  Toast.makeText(this, "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Соглашусь с ответом Никиты Васильченко, но добавлю, что есть и более элегантный способ сверки строк, и, что важно, `null-safe`:

```
TextUtils.equals(string1, string2);
```